# Removal of elements from list containing substring like 'Page 1 of 67' or 'Page 2 of 67'

Tags: python-3.x, list

I have a list in python where certain elements contain substring like 'Page 1 of 67' , 'Page 2 of 67' and so on till 'Page 67 of 67'.

list1 = ["24/02/2021| Page 1 of 67|", "Wealth Protect Assure 2 - 100| 100| 500,000.00| 9,000.00| 750.00|", "Proposed By: Sample Agent 012| Ver 7.14.0| Page 2 of 67|", "Deduct fees & charges"]

output = ["Wealth Protect Assure 2 - 100| 100| 500,000.00| 9,000.00| 750.00|","Deduct fees & charges"]

Comment: Split by `|`, check for content and remove if matches. OR - `RegEx`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
list1 = ["24/02/2021| Page 1 of 67|", "Wealth Protect Assure 2 - 100| 100| 500,000.00| 9,000.00| 750.00|", "Proposed By: Sample Agent 012| Ver 7.14.0| Page 2 of 67|", "Deduct fees & charges"]
print([i for i in list1 if "Page" not in i])
```

Output:

```
['Wealth Protect Assure 2 - 100| 100| 500,000.00| 9,000.00| 750.00|', 'Deduct fees & charges']
```

Comment: Hi, Would have to improve the regex pattern:
pattern = re.compile(r"\| Page \d of \d+\|") as it fails for Page 10 of 67 onwards.
So it will be re.compile(r"\| Page \d+ of \d+\|")

Comment: Then use this `pattern = re.compile(r"\| Page \d+ of \d+\|")`

Answer (score 0):

import re

pattern = re.compile(r"| Page \d+ of \d+|")
list1 = ["24/02/2021| Page 10 of 67|", "Wealth Protect Assure 2 - 100| 100| 500,000.00| 9,000.00| 750.00|",
"Proposed By: Sample Agent 012| Ver 7.14.0| Page 20 of 67|", "Deduct fees & charges"]

filtered = [i for i in list1 if not pattern.search(i)]

print(filtered)